# Decode the meaning of "FileDateTime" value in PHP Function exif_read_data()

Tags: php

Is it possible to decode the meaning of **"FileDateTime" Value** in PHP Function `exif_read_data()`?

This is the sample output of my picture file:

```
Array ( [FileName] => Oppa Heart.jpg 
[FileDateTime] => 1675131949 
[FileSize] => 91688 
[FileType] => 2 
[MimeType] => image/jpeg 
[SectionsFound] => 
[COMPUTED] => Array ( 
     [html] => width="800" height="881" 
     [Height] => 881 
     [Width] => 800 
     [IsColor] => 1 ) 
)
```

Comment: `(new \DatetimeImmutable())->setTimestamp(1675131949)->format(\DatetimeImmutable::ATOM)`. More on formats here: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetimeimmutable.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

The value `1675131949` from `FileDateTime` is unix timestamp. You can surely change it into human readable timestamp format using [DATE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (looks more simple) or  [DateTimeImmutable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php).

Example to do this using `DATE`

```
<?php
$unix_timestamp = 1675131949;

$human_readable = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix_timestamp);

echo $human_readable;
```

Output will be

```
2023-01-31 02:25:49
```

You can read [DateTime format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) to get your desire format of output

Additionally, if you want to change this time in specific timezone then you can use [date_default_timezone_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)